# Basic Select Input

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am having trouble with creating a basic Select input...

app/controllers/scratch.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    list: ['green', 'red', 'blue']
});
```

app/routes/scratch.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
});
```

app/templates/scratch.js

```
{{outlet}}
{{view "select" content=list}}
```

Chrome Console:

> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Unable to find view at path 'select'

Wha....

Comment: Gah....`{{view "select" content=list}}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
{{view "Ember.Select" content=list}}
```

Comment: Ahhh.. Thank you.. Can you do the rest of their documentation as well? (+1)

Comment: @SethMcClaine as andrew-hacking stated above, Ember 1.8.1 and up fixe that behaviour and even raise deprecation message to use jim's first syntax

Comment: I was referring to their general documentation, its a little weak

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue and used `{{ view 'Ember.Select' ...}}` however I believe Ember 1.8.1 fixes an issue with resolving views so you should be able to just do `{{view 'select' content=list}}` now.

Comment: I can confirm that after updating to version 1.8.1 this issue disappeared.